# What's wrong with typeof a == "array"?

Tags: typescript

Try at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html):

```
typeof a == "array"
```

will result in

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to types '"string" | "number" | "symbol" | "object" | "function"' and '"array"'.)

Not only doesn't this error message make no sense to me (`typeof a == "object"` is just fine), it seems to be a recent change, too. You now have to use `a instanceof Array`, which was not necessary last time I checked. Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: The `typeof` operator can never return that.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: ah, I see, thanks. interesting this was never a problem in former versions

Comment: It never worked, but TypeScript only became smart enough to warn you about it in 2.0.

Comment: Or `Array.isArray(a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by SLaks, the typeof operator can never return "array". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

It never worked, but TypeScript only became smart enough to warn you about it in 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example for you:

```
var a: string | string[];

// You need this in the example to ensure the compiler won't determine that a
// is never a string if you set it to an array...
if (new Date().getDay() > 3) {
    a = 'a string';
} else {
    a = [
        'an',
        'array'
    ];
}

if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    var example1 = a; // example1: string[]
} else {
    var example2 = a; // example2: string
}
```

The middle code block is needed for demonstration purposes only, if you start this example with `var a: string | string[] = []` the variable `example2` will actually end up being of type `never` because the compiler is smart enough to see that there is no case where the `a` variable will be set to anything except an array.